# TCPDF margin and custom page size issue

Tags: php, format, margin, tcpdf

At first, I will define as A4 size.

Then when found the page width and height via some dynamic computation from database, I will override it by using `$resolution`.

I need the page margin to top and to left all zero.

Then `setxy` will assign the item into absolute position via cm measurement.

However, it keep on getting extra margin space from left and from top...

When printing, I am selecting print with actual size

```
global $l;

$l = Array();
$l['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$l['a_meta_dir'] = 'ltr';
$l['a_meta_language'] = 'en';
$l['w_page'] = 'page';

require_once('../tcpdf.php');
$PDF_PAGE_FORMAT= 'A4';
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'cm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('courier');
$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0, true);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

$pdfWidth= "30";
$pdfHeight= "15";
$resolution= array($pdfWidth, $pdfHeight);

$pdf->AddPage('L', $resolution, $keepmargins=true);
$pdf->SetXY(1,2,true);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans','B',8);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,"test 123",0,1,'L');
$pdf->SetXY(20,7,true);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans','B',8);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,"Title 2",1,0,'L');

$pdfdata= $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'S');
```